# Is the keyword meta tag required?

Tags: html, meta-tags

Is the `keywords` meta tag required in an html document head?

It seems to me it is not, from the W3 description of the document structure: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html. But I can't find anywhere where they say it directly.

The reason is that I have heard people argumenting that it should always be present. Even empty. My question is not regarding the usefulness of the tag, but just if it is required or should always be present of some reason or not.

Comment: hope no one down votes this question.. ;) i've seen ur discussion in meta :)

Comment: @Bhuvan Rikka. Haha :) No, please do! But tell me, what I do wrong while you are at it :D

Comment: I support u bro :)...Even i hate anonymous down voting...it'd be better if we can see who downvotes our posts ;)

Comment: @Bhuvan Rikka. Good to know a fellow! :) Well, anonymity is key in the voting system and I understand that. But we would be better off, if a downvoter was required to leave at least an anonymous comment as I see it.

Comment: ya that reduces little pain ;) at least we can learn about our mistake if it is logical

Comment: Kinda funny I got -8 by now on that meta question :) (Yea yea, I know, its a different voting system on meta - but still...)

Comment: if i were u,i wud have removed the question by now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta tag is optional. The formal rule that implies this is the content model for the head element, saying that all sub-elements except the title element are optional.

Answer (score 3):

No. It was an old technique for SSO. Web browsers basically ignore it. Search engines *may* (mostly) ignore it today.

Answer (score 1):

The `keywords` meta tag is, and has always been, optional.

If you don't have any content for the meta tag, remove it out entirely.